# Logout doesn't redirect - Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, logout

Logout is successfuly performed and user is disconnected. The problem is that it doesn't redirect to the page set in configuration. It gives instead a 500 Internal Error with following error message:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Parent
>   session handler is not open in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\community\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 398

I am using Symfony2.3.25 and PHP 5.4.7.

My security configuration is:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/
        logout:                 
            path: /logout
            target: /
        anonymous:  ~
```

When I refresh the logout path in browser, it successfully redirects to home page.

Any clue is much appreciated.

Comment: which version of php and of the framework are you using?

Comment: @Matteo, thanks for looking at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a problem related to PHP, has mentioned in the **[SymfonyRequirements](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/commit/2a518e7)**  for php version before 5.4.11:

> When using the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component, you
>   should have at least PHP 5.4.11 due to PHP bug #63379 (as a
>   workaround, you can also set invalidate_session to false in the
>   security logout handler configuration)

Has workaround you can add `invalidate_session: false`:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/
        logout:                 
            path: /logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: false
        anonymous:  ~
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Waaw! I was reading my log and stack trace and it is saying that problem is related to session and session handler. +1, I will implement this and come give a feedback. thank you very much